# Redshift row_number() or dense_rank() over repeated same name campaigns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have campaigns that take a few days and when a campaign finish a new one starts.
My goal is to find unique customers for each campaigns

The table like this:

```
  |customer| date| campaign|  
 ---------------------------- 
  | a | 2019-01-01 | C-A  |   
  | a | 2019-01-02 | C-A  |   
  | a | 2019-01-03 | C-A  |   
  | b | 2019-01-01 | C-A  |   
  | b | 2019-01-03 | C-A  |   
  | c | 2019-01-02 | C-A  |   
  | d | 2019-01-04 | C-B  |   
  | d | 2019-01-05 | C-B  |   
  | e | 2019-01-05 | C-B  |   
  | a | 2019-01-06 | C-C  |   
  | c | 2019-01-07 | C-C  |   
  | f | 2019-01-07 | C-C  |   
  | f | 2019-01-08 | C-C  |   
  | g | 2019-01-09 | C-A  |   
  | a | 2019-01-09 | C-A  |   
  | b | 2019-01-10 | C-A  |
  | c | 2019-01-10 | C-A  |
```

but the problem is some campaign names repeated over the time e.g: Campaign `C-A` repeated after a few days later in the example table above but this should be a different campaign. when I tried `dense_rank()` or `row_number()` all include all same campaign names I tried to use partition by I cannot use date because campaigns take a few days.

The result that I want to find this:

```
|customer| date| campaign| unique-customer|
| ------------------------------------ | 
| a | 2019-01-01 | C-A  | 3 |
| a | 2019-01-02 | C-A  | 3 |
| a | 2019-01-03 | C-A  | 3 |
| b | 2019-01-01 | C-A  | 3 |
| b | 2019-01-03 | C-A  | 3 |
| c | 2019-01-02 | C-A  | 3 |
| d | 2019-01-04 | C-B  | 2 |
| d | 2019-01-05 | C-B  | 2 |
| e | 2019-01-05 | C-B  | 2 |
| a | 2019-01-06 | C-C  | 3 |
| c | 2019-01-07 | C-C  | 3 |
| f | 2019-01-07 | C-C  | 3 |
| f | 2019-01-08 | C-C  | 3 |
| g | 2019-01-09 | C-A  | 4 |
| a | 2019-01-09 | C-A  | 4 |
| b | 2019-01-10 | C-A  | 4 |
| c | 2019-01-10 | C-A  | 4 |
```

how can I partition the campaign over time.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this.  One is gaps-and-islands.  The second is counting unique customers.  For the former, you can use the difference of row numbers.  For the latter, you can use `row_number()` to count the first occurrence.

So:

```
select t.*,
       sum( (seqnum_cust = 1)::int ) over (partition by campaign, seqnum - seqnum_c) as num_unique_customers
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by campaign, seqnum - seqnum_c, customer order by date) as seqnum_cust
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by campaign order by date) as seqnum_c
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff for the answer. It is what I wanted. I have one more question, please.  I have a bit of large data, and this takes ages to find the answer. Basically, If I need only a unique customer number for each date and event how can I improve more. Thanks

Comment: @Axis. . . You can try indexes on `(campaign, date)` and (date)`.  However, you presumably have a very large amount of data, so that is only a partial solution.

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT customer,dt,campaign,COUNT(DISTINCT customer) OVER (PARTITION BY campaign) AS Unique_Customer
 FROM campaign;`